# Adding a message to FacesContext disables autocomplete

Tags: java, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm trying to show a message when a autocomplete selection is made. It shows the message, but when i try to use the autocomplete again it doesn't execute my completeMethod.

View:

```
   <p:messages id="gNewDiagnostic" for="guau" escape="false"/>       
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="panelGridForm">
                <p:outputLabel value="Patología:" for="pathologyND"/>
                <p:autoComplete id="pathologyND" value="#{newDiagnostic.pathology}" completeMethod="#{newDiagnostic.completeTextPathology}">
                    <p:ajax event="blur" listener ="#{newDiagnostic.warningGest}"/>
                </p:autoComplete>
                <p:outputLabel value="Estado del Diagnóstico:" for="stateDiagnosticND" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="stateDiagnosticND" value="#{newDiagnostic.stateDiagnostic}">
                    <p:ajax update="gNewDiagnostic" listener="#{newDiagnostic.warningGest}">
                    </p:ajax>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione un Item" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sospecha" itemValue="sospecha" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Confirmado" itemValue="confirmado" />                    
                </p:selectOneMenu>               
            </p:panelGrid>
```

Managed Bean:

```
public void warningGest() {
    boolean type = diseasesFacade.diseaseType(pathology);
    stateGes = true;

    if (type == true && stateDiagnostic.equals("confirmado")) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("guau", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Advertencia", "La patología " + pathology + " es una enfermedad GES. "));
        stateGes = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was in a growl nested in the parent form. The growl missed some attributes and  had the property `autoUpdate=true` causing failure in all ajax processing after a message was added to the context.

Deleting the growl fixed the issue.